# trying to understand "Simon" game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm Working on Simon game. I need help with understanding how to reference an id and creating an action without a click but say with page refresh.

1) on screen refresh (the start of the game), I CAN randomize the color id chosen...and save it in a var called randomColorChosen... but I can NOT figure out how to make that var randomColorChosen, make the same actions as if they were a clicked on button like my code at the bottom.

2) My btn click and animate color and play sound... work fine,

I have tried many iterations of my newbie coding...
Now I'm just guessing and here is it's last state....

... random Color Chosen works... its what's next I need help (explanations on)

... `$(document).keydown(function(event) {}` works and tested with an alert()

... but the rest, down until my but clicks, I have changed so many times my head is spinning. Help my understand where I am dumb AF! lol

... user btn click event action and sound... works fine!

Here is my code so far:

```js
buttonColors=["btn green","btn red", "btn yellow", "btn blue"];
randomColorChosen=buttonColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * (buttonColors.length))];
$(document).keydown(function(event) { 
setTimeout(2000);  
    $("#id").attr(function(randomColorChosen){
        $(this).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
          var myPadColor = $(this).attr("#id");
        });
      });
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function(event) {
      $(this).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);//when a "this" button is clicked .fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
      var myPadColor = $(this).attr("class");
       ;
      switch (myPadColor) {
        case "btn green":
          var greenPad = new Audio('sounds/green.mp3');
          greenPad.play();
          break;
        case "btn red":
          var redPad = new Audio('sounds/red.mp3');
          redPad.play();
          break;
        case "btn yellow":
          var yellowPad = new Audio('sounds/yellow.mp3');
          yellowPad.play();
          break;
        case "btn blue":
          var bluePad = new Audio('sounds/blue.mp3');
          bluePad.play();
          break;
        default:
          console.log(myPadColor);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your current example is riddled with issues and it's not clear what you have tried or what is not working specifically.

Comment: You probably want to test for a `localStorage` property onload, setting the property on some Event, like `addEventListener('load', function(){ if(someElement.color){ /* do something with color */ } someElement.onclick = function(){ localStorage.color = 'yellow'; } });`

Comment: The part of my code that does not work is...   $("#id").attr(function(randomColorChosen){
        $(this).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
          var myPadColor = $(this).attr("#id");
        });
      });                                                                           my code starts, on the .keydown What I want is for the randomColorChosen variable, to also be able to randomly select a myPadColor, animate it, as well as play its sound. This is all done with the purpose of being the "firstMove" by the game.

Comment: @Bryant you have shown your code, you have not shown the corresponding HTML. Please provide a better example.

Comment: <body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">
        <h2>G</h2>
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">
        <h2>R</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">
      <h2>Y</h2>
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">
        <h2>B</h2>
      </div>  THE REST OF THE BODY IS THE SAME, But with the respective color

Answer (score 1):

It was a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish. I created an example with some possible improved code.

```js
$(function() {
  var seq = [];
  var player = [];
  var c;
  var round = 0;
  var sounds = [
    new Audio('sounds/green.mp3'),
    new Audio('sounds/red.mp3'),
    new Audio('sounds/yellow.mp3'),
    new Audio('sounds/blue.mp3')
  ];

  function getRandom() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  }

  function initSeq(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      seq.push(getRandom());
    }
  }

  function flash(b) {
    //console.log("Flashing Button " + b);
    var btn = $("#game-board .btn").eq(b);
    btn.fadeTo(300, 1.0, function() {
      btn.fadeTo(300, 0.35);
    });
    sounds[b].play();
  }

  function endGame() {
    $("#game-board").hide();
    $("h1").show();
    $("h1").after("<h2>Gome Over. Score: " + player.length + "</h2>");
  }

  function waitUserInput() {
    c = setInterval(endGame, 10 * 1000);
  }

  function playSequence(x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == undefined) {
      x = 20;
    }
    $.each(seq, function(i, s) {
      if (i < x) {
        flash(s);
      }
    });
  }

  function nextRound() {
    playSequence(++round);
  }

  function initGame() {
    initSeq(20);
    player = [];
    c = null;
    round = 0;
    nextRound();
  }

  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    $("h1").hide();
    $("#game-board").show();
    initGame();
  });

  $("#game-board .btn").click(function(event) {
    var i = $(this).index();
    flash(i);
    player.push(i);
  });

  $("#playSeq").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).next().val();
    console.log("TEST: Play Sequence to " + p + " Position.");
    if (seq.length == 0) {
      initSeq(20);
      $("#game-board").show();
    }
    //console.log("TEST", seq);
    playSequence(p);
  });
});
```

```css
#game-board {
  width: 410px;
  white-space: normal;
}

.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.35;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 199px 0 0 0;
}

.red {
  border: 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0 199px 0 0;
}

.yellow {
  border: 0;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.65;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 199px;
}

.blue {
  border: 0;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.65;
  border-radius: 0 0 199px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-bar">
  <button id="playSeq">Play To</button> <input type="number" value="1" style="width: 2.5em;" />
</div>
<h1>Press Any Key to Begin.</h1>
<div id="game-board" style="display: none;">
  <div class="btn green"></div>
  <div class="btn red"></div>
  <div class="btn yellow"></div>
  <div class="btn blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Twisty  What I an trying to do is, at the first loading of the page, have nothing happen. The user just sees the game. It's h1 heading reads as "Press any key to begin the game."  Then my code starts, on the .keydown (I know how to change the h1 to read "Level 1") What I want  is for the randomColorChosen variable, to also be able to randomly select a myPadColor,  animate it, as well as play its sound.  This is all done with the purpose of being the "firstMove" by the game, in what will become the first item in an array created by the game, in which the user will have to  ===

Comment: I'm intentionally... looking for help with this one beginning part... so that it will force me to put to use, what I think I know versus what I actually know.  User Moves such as, Click on button, make animation, play a sound... I can do (as shown)... But right now I am stuck on the "automated" aka The Game's opening move.  Next the game's random move, as an entry into an array... but I think I can work that out ;-)

Comment: @Bryant this is not the website for that. It is best to try some code or learn about a snippet of code and when you get to a point that you can't see past, then post a question. You have to put the effort in first. I would take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Bryant you might also like: https://codepen.io/BenLBlood/pen/LGLEoJ

Comment: And for the record... I do admit my bad when realized... Sooo.... I DID checkout the code pen link... Maybe I took this a little too personally... It's a vulnerable feeling when you feel stupid... and it seems like someone publicly confirms it by saying "this is the wrong website for you! Anyway... Thanks for that link... but I already do have access to the answer. It's the way my class solved it... I was trying to understand  the project better by solving with it my own logic... Hence asking for help with MY LOGIC... Anyway... #no hard feelings! #debugged #Code Life!