# How to setup a proper for loop JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to work up a simple JQuery styled simon says game, the idea is to call up the nextSequence add that to an array so simon knows which buttons to animate for the player, i.e. gamePattern = ["green","blue","red"]; in doing so simon should animate the button green, THEN the button blue, and so on and so forth for as long as it needs to. i tried setting up a for loop/forEach to get it to loop through the array, and at each interval the code should do an animation for that button. however the problem is, it does the animation to all intervals. so instead of doing it one at a time, itll do it to all three elements. though if i have repeating elements, like say "green" "green" "red", it will do both green and red once, and then do green once more.

ive been messing with this code for hours and i cant understand why its doing this, i even setup a timeOut function set to a second, in hopes that would offer a buffer but it seems intent on doing this to all elements.

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = []


function simon(pattern) {
  pattern.forEach((item, i) => {
    //1. Use jQuery to select the button with the same id as the randomChosenColour
    //2. Use Google/Stackoverflow to figure out how you can use jQuery to animate a flash to the button selected in step 1.
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($("#" + item).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100));
    }, 1000);

    //3. Use Google/Stackoverflow to figure out how you can use Javascript to play the sound for the button colour selected in step 1.
    // var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + [i] + ".mp3");
    // audio.play();

  });

}

function nextSequence() {
  //Generate a random number from 0 - 3,
  var randomNumber = getRandomInt(4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);


  return randomNumber;
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
  //Returns a random integer up to but not including (max) i.e. max = 3, will return numbers from 0-2
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML, CSS and images (placeholder.com)

Comment: Since it's a webpage, it's not immediately helpful to use a game loop. There are ways to do this with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. For a game like Simon Says, you would trigger a loop when the users has to be presented with the new pattern. Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725424/trying-to-understand-simon-game/59726493?

Comment: i included the HTML and CSS pages, so it can be reproduced locally. youll have to use the console in the local page, call up nextSequence() and then pass the gamePattern to the function simon() as i have yet to get it far enough to do all of this without needing to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An english-language translation of this code:

```
pattern.forEach((item, i) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + item).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  }, 1000);
});
```

would be, "for each of these items, in one second, fade it in, then out, and then in again."

So the loop runs, all the timeouts are scheduled for the same time -- one second from now -- and then when that second elapses, all of them fire at once.

Meanwhile, jQuery helpfully queues up any animations that are set on the same element to run sequentially, which is where you're getting the behavior you're seeing on "green green red" -- you're simultaneously setting up two animations on green and one on red, they start all at once, and the green queue has twice as much animation to do as the red one.

The confusion here is that you're expecting the code to wait the full second for each timeout in the loop, which doesn't happen.  You could use async/await to force the loop to wait for each iteration to complete before continuing, or use jQuery's end-of-animation callback to kick off the next iteration, but it might be easiest in this case to just set them each on a different timeout:

```
pattern.forEach((item, i) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#" + item).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  }, i * 300); // <-- note the timeout
});
```

(Your animation takes 300ms in total, so I set it to `i*300` so the 2nd timeout will fire just as the first animation is ending, and so on.  The loop starts with i=0 so the first timeout will fire immediately, which is probably what you want anyway.)

Comment: I took your example, but changed the i * 300, to 1000, and this seems to work. this gives i believe the right amount of buffer between calls that the player would notice it. however i would like to know more about the last bit, so i * 300, since all animations are loaded, simply just makes them wait a certain amount of time before they fire index 0, would fire immediately and index 1 would fire after 300ms right?

Comment: WHy not use the callback from fadeIn/Out to do the next call? They are delayed animations anyway

Comment: @AustinHoward yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: @mplungjan that'd work too, of course - I try to change as little as possible when answering questions just so it's clearer what I'm doing, but I'll add that suggestion to the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Daniel's answer is more specific to the question, please see above. Have left this here as it might be useful for reference in similar projects.** Have upvoted Daniel's answer.

Here's a basic example of the game, you'll need to tweak it depending on your requirements but it has the functionality of a simple simon says game. It randomly sets the correct colour, cycles through them, recognises when the user correctly clicks the button and then stops the game, and lets them restart.

I've used the `setInterval` function and the code is fully commented.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// Create array of colours
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

// Start a new game
newGame();



// Function to start game
function newGame() {

  // Randomly get index for winning color
  var r = getRandomInt(buttonColors.length);

  // Assign winning color
  $("#correctColor").css("background-color", buttonColors[r]).text(buttonColors[r]);

  // Start interval for game
  game = setInterval(function() {

      // Update color for button
      $("#simonSays").css("background-color", buttonColors[getRandomInt(buttonColors.length)]);
    }, 1000 // every 1 second
  );

}




// Check for play clicking button
$("#simonSays").click(function() {

  // Check if game has ended
  if ($(this).text() == "New Game") {
  
    // Reset button
    $(this).text("Simon Says");
    
    // Start a new game
    newGame();
    
    // Leave function
    return;
    
  }

  // Check if button color is same as winning color
  if ($(this).css("background-color") == $("#correctColor").css("background-color")) {

    // Send console message to prove we know
    console.log("Correct!");
    
    // Change button text
    $(this).text("New Game");

    // Stop game
    clearInterval(game);

  }

});




function getRandomInt(max) {
  //Returns a random integer up to but not including (max) i.e. max = 3, will return numbers from 0-2
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

```css
.correctColor,
#simonSays {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Press on the button when it is <span id="correctColor" style="color:white;">blue</span> to stop the cycle.</p>
<button id="simonSays" style="color:white;">Simon Says</button>
```